# Differentiate between folders and symbolic links on Windows

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I created some symbolic links for some folders when I had Windows Server 2008 R2 installed. Now I have formatted and installed Windows 7.

The symlinks are still there but I don't know how to differentiate between them and normal folders! `dir /AL` returns `File not found`.

Can anyone explain how to differentiate between symbolic links and folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you formatted - does this mean that you have copied or moved the folders somewhere between using them with the two OSes? Maybe they went through a backup / restore cycle?

If so, they probably are not symlinks any more, but just standard copies.

Comment: That's right; I backed up the folder where I had other files along with the symlinks by zipping up everything. And indeed when I delete one of the folders, or any of them, there's always the files remaining; so I guess it's like you said; they became copies... thanks a lot for this!!